# Is there a way to create a perpetual checking system in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, I am trying to create this checking system in Google Sheets to track progress on my student's PT progress. Below is how the system should work. This whole thing is really complicated, so will require some patience to understand the way everything works. I am also open to suggestions of different apps, but previously it has always been done using Google Sheets and I have to make it so other classes can use it and the head can view it so I am continuing with it.

Currently, I have to track something called Heat Acclimatization (HA) for our students. The first condition is to have 2 exercises within a 7-day frame then after the second exercise, the next day will be counted as Rest Day 1. Next, we have to conduct 2 more exercises again before the 14th day starting from Rest Day 1, and the latter 2 exercises have to be conducted within 7 days of each other, and the cycle continues every week. 2 exercises can be conducted on the same or different days.

I am hoping that I can receive help with the Google Sheets formula that can make the scenario I described feasible. I have added examples of how the system should work.

[HA Maintained Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4z9B.jpg)

[HA Maintained Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwjPq.jpg)

[HA Maintained Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhxid.jpg)

[HA Maintained Example 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMRkr.jpg)

[HA Lapsed Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl0lT.jpg)

[HA Lapsed Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuznH.jpg)

[HA Lapsed Example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xowuf.jpg)

I am also working on my own way of tracking this but I feel stuck because there are just too many variables. This is what I've come up with so far. Basically I only need to key in the date of qualification and the rest will be automated.

"Checker 1" checks whether the next 2 HA activity after the qualification date, in this case "HA 1" and "HA 2" is within 7 days of each other and if it is within 14 days of the qualification date. I am coding this manually now, but I would like if it can automatically find the next 2 HA after the qualification date (excluding the day itself, like in Gary's case it should only start counting from "HA 3" and not "HA 2")

"Checker 2" checks whether the student's HA maintained correctly based on the examples given on top. It is very complicated, so what I did is once the student passes "Checker 1", the cell will turn "TRUE" and it will run a code checking whether (Christian) "HA 3" and "HA 4" is within 7 days of each other, whether "HA 4" is within 15 days of "HA 2" and whether "HA 1" and "HA 2" is within 7 days of each other. Once all 3 conditions are fulfilled, then "Checker 2" will turn "TRUE".

Now onto the problems I foresee. Firstly, I need checker 2 to keep tracking this whenever we conduct a new activity, and since I have essentially grouped them into pairs, I should only check the 2nd one of the pair which to be honest I have no idea how to do.

Secondly, in the case of John, his "Checker 1" checks against "HA 4" and "HA 5" which violates "Checker 1" rule of the 2 activities being 7 day apart from each other but it does not go against the logic of the example I gave on top, which if the first HA activity is done within 7 days of qualification, the next 2 HA activity just needs to be within 14 days of the initial HA and 7 days of each other.

Lastly, based on the example if HA activities are conducted within 7 days of each other, the rest day will reset which will kind of throw everything in chaos. For example, if I were to shift "HA 3" to 28/11/23, I can technically conduct "HA 4" and "HA 5" within 7 days of each other and as long as "HA 5" is within 15 days of "HA 3"

| Name | Date of Qualification | Checker 1 | Checker 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Christian | 06/11/23 | True | True |
| Gary | 21/11/23 | True | True |
| John | 28/11/23 | False | False |

| HA 1 | HA 2 | HA 3 | HA 4 | HA 5 | HA 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14/11/23 | 21/11/23 | 29/11/23 | 6/12/23 | 19/12/23 | 20/12/23 |

Comment: Decide between Excel or Googlesheets, they are different.